# Why does "^" on a data.frame return a matrix instead of a data.frame like "*" does?

Tags: r, dataframe, operators, exponentiation

This question is motivated by a [bug filed here by Abiel Reinhart](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5071&group_id=240&atid=975) on `data.table`. I noticed that the same happens on `data.frame` as well.

Here's an example:

```
DF <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10)
> DF*DF
   x   y
1  1  36
2  4  49
3  9  64
4 16  81
5 25 100

> class(DF*DF) # [1] "data.frame"

> DF^2
      x   y
[1,]  1  36
[2,]  4  49
[3,]  9  64
[4,] 16  81
[5,] 25 100

> class(DF^2) # [1] "matrix"
```

Why does "^" coerce it into a matrix? Any ideas? Note that `**` is converted to `^` by the parser. So, doing `DF**2` would give the same result as `DF^2`.

I don't find anything related to this coercion in `` ?`^` ``.

**Edit:** Neal's answer shows clearly the reason for `^` returning a `matrix` when operated on a `data.frame`. It'd be great if the question as to **why** `^` is being left out in that piece of code could be answered as well.

**Edit 2:** I also posted [here on R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-November/363098.html) and got a reply from Duncan that there seems to be no info reg. this change in the NEWS (admittedly, it's a quite old change as Joshua and Duncan also pointed out).

Comment: Then it's a feature request? Unless you *prefer* the default.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Ops.data.frame` implements the math operators for data frames as S3 generics, here is the last couple lines:

```
if (.Generic %in% c("+", "-", "*", "/", "%%", "%/%")) {
    names(value) <- cn
    data.frame(value, row.names = rn, check.names = FALSE, 
        check.rows = FALSE)
}
else matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), 
    nrow = nr, dimnames = list(rn, cn))
```

So `^` gets returned as a matrix.

Comment: :) Great. Very nice find! Now any idea why `^` is missed out there??

Comment: It looks like that line was written in R 2.2.0 back in the day, according to [this repo](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blame/master/src/library/base/R/dataframe.R#L1528), so I would chalk it up to 'legacy behavior'.

Comment: You can easily redefine `Ops.data.frame` to include `"^"` in the vector of permissible functions. It will return a `data.frame` with correct results, but I am sure R-Core will have a (good?) reason as to why it is not there in the first place. Perhaps this one should be put to either r-help or r-devel.

Comment: That line has existed in roughly that form since revision 3475 on 1999-01-29. If it was a mistake, I seriously doubt you could change it now without breaking things.

Comment: @Arun are you gonna ask why it is so on one of the *real* mailing lists? I'd be interested to know the response.

Comment: @Arun the honour of a possible flame roast is yours.